# ServiceNow CLI "snc: command not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, path, command-line-interface, servicenow

I'm having trouble getting the [SN CLI](https://github.com/ServiceNow/servicenow-cli) working on my work laptop.

Something to note is that I've installed via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@servicenow/cli), i.e. npm i @servicenow/cli -g instead of the installer because I do not have admin privileges on my work laptop.

Setup:

- Python v3.11.4
- Node v14.21.3
- npm v6.14.18
- now-cli v23.0.0
- Windows 10
- Git BASH

So the weird thing is that when I do now-cli --version, I get a version number back and it seems to be working:

[image]

However, the snc commands don't seem to be recognized:
[image]

I realize the [Now CLI docs](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/next-experience/utah/cli/getting-started) says the CLI is only compatible with Node v12; however, I was following [this](https://youtu.be/-lwAct1WnBU) and [this](https://youtu.be/QjUk1HnZwp4) tutorial and they both had Node v14 and were able to get it working. I have tried both Node v12 and v14, and I am experiencing the same issue.

Thank you,

Jorge